# Error while compiling native audio sample

Tags: android-ndk

I am new to Android native ,trying to compile the native audio sample (Android 2.3),
while compiling it showing the error :undeclared as follows

its is the part of my errors:

```
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:562: error: 'bqPlayerObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:565: error: 'bqPlayerPlay' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:566: error: 'bqPlayerBufferQueue' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:567: error: 'bqPlayerEffectSend' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:571: error: 'fdPlayerObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:574: error: 'fdPlayerPlay' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:575: error: 'fdPlayerSeek' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:579: error: 'uriPlayerObject' undeclared(first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:582: error: 'uriPlayerPlay' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:583: error: 'uriPlayerSeek' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:587: error: 'recorderObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:590: error: 'recorderRecord' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:591: error: 'recorderBufferQueue' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:595: error: 'outputMixObject' undeclared(first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:598: error: 'outputMixEnvironmentalReverb' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:602: error: 'engineObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
apps/na/project/jni/native-audio-jni.c:605: error: 'engineEngine' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [out/apps/na/armeabi/objs/native-audio-jni/native-audio-jni.o] Error 1
```

Can any one help  me to compile it? I never came across the openMAX api's before.

Comment: Do you have any code you could post? Or is this an error compiling only the example?

Comment: that is an error came while compiling the ndk-r5c native audio samples thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Me also have the same problem plz .... any solution?????????

Comment: @thegrinner..error compiling example